# Using salt-ssh for Ubuntu/Debian patching (dialog frontend is not usable)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, saltstack, patch-management

I'm looking into replacing a Linux based home-grown patch management solution with `salt-ssh`.

The current system uses a shell script to iterate through a list of hosts and copies a script named *apt-update* to the remote. After copying the script, the process then runs the script on the remote (over ssh). The *apt-update* script basically contains `apt-get udpate; apt-get upgrade`. When a conflict arises with a configuration file (such as Grub) or `dpkg-reconfigure` runs something like `pam-auth-update`, interaction is required to select how to proceed. If I run this process over `salt-ssh`, there doesn't seem to be an opportunity to interact with the update process. In fact, `salt-ssh` stdout contains this:

```
stderr:
  debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
  debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
  debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
  debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
  debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
  debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
  dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

I've not used Saltstack before. Is there a way to handle this type of situation when interaction is required?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in order to cause all such questions to be suppressed. However, how packages get configured in this scenario may vary, so you should test thoroughly.